# Typescript with custom react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typescript-typings

Trying to write a custom react hook in TypeScript that accepts an object with all optional React.CSSProperties as keys like so...

```js
const something = useSomthing({
  color: {
    initial: 'red',
    new: 'blue'
  }
})
```

Can I write it in a way that i'll get all the css properties in the IDE autocomplete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `keyof` and read more [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

```
type Config = {
  [key in keyof React.CSSProperties]?: {
    initial: React.CSSProperties[key];
    new: React.CSSProperties[key];
  }
};

const useSomething = (config:Config)=>{
   ...
}
```

Comment: That's not much help if you end up with having the right side being "any" though.

Comment: The example shows custom body of the key so I put any there. The question was about the autocomplete so I think it helps a lot. Also, I put a reference to the documentation where you can see how you can use the key. I think the right side is easy to create :)